# How do I set a Boolean field with "yes" and "no" values?

Tags: nodes

[image]I have a content type, I'm trying to add a field that's a boolean. I want the options to be yes or no. This is something I thought would be relatively simple however, I keep getting an error message. I've attached 2 screenshots. 1 is the configuration for my boolean. The other is the error message my site gets. Can someone help me. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boolean field accept only `0` and `1` as value.
if you want to add allowed values by PHP Code should be:

```
0|No
1|Yes
```

I create a Boolean field on Content type and i set the `On value` to `Yes` and
 `off Value` to `No`.
As you see In the below screenshot the value of input is `0` for `NO` and `1` for `Yes`.
[image]

Comment: I followed your screenshot and did it exactly how you did. I'm still getting an error message it says "ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER) in cck_allowed_values_php() (line 2 "